# Problem with the derivative of a dataframe with two variables

Tags: r, derivative

I'm trying to get the derivative of a dataset with two variables (age, weight). With the two variables I can get a distance curve (weight for age: y=kg, x=age), and the curve is smooth:

[weight for age showing the data pairs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0I6qN.jpg)

My objective is to get the velocity curve (weight gain per year by age: y=kg/year, x= age). So, I'm trying to get the derivative for each point with the following:

```
d1=diff(anthropometry_hw$weight)/diff(anthropometry_hw$age)
```

But the output is not correct, the derivative looks like this:

[derivative for weight for age](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xkx1S.jpg)

The data come from an anthropometric study, and the derivative should look smooth, without all those ups and downs. The same formula works correctly with other data, so I don't know what is going on. I would really appreciate if somebody with experience could help me.

These are the data:

```
 age weight
```

1   0.00     3.1
2   0.25     5.9
3   0.50     7.4
4   0.75     8.2
5   1.00     9.0
6   1.25     9.5
7   1.50    10.1
8   1.75    10.8
9   2.00    11.2
10  2.25    11.7
11  2.50    12.2
12  2.75    12.6
13  3.00    13.1
14  3.25    13.6
15  3.50    14.3
16  3.75    14.9
17  4.00    15.5
18  4.25    16.0
19  4.50    16.5
20  4.75    17.1
21  5.00    17.5
22  5.25    17.9
23  5.50    18.5
24  5.75    19.1
25  6.00    19.7
26  6.25    20.4
27  6.50    21.1
28  6.75    21.7
29  7.00    22.4
30  7.25    23.0
31  7.50    23.6
32  7.75    24.4
33  8.00    25.1
34  8.25    25.9
35  8.50    26.6
36  8.75    27.4
37  9.00    28.3
38  9.25    29.1
39  9.50    29.9
40  9.75    30.9
41 10.00    32.0
42 10.25    33.0
43 10.50    34.0
44 10.75    35.2
45 11.00    36.5
46 11.25    37.7
47 11.50    38.9
48 11.75    40.2
49 12.00    41.4
50 12.25    42.7
51 12.50    43.9
52 12.75    44.8
53 13.00    45.7
54 13.25    46.6
55 13.50    47.5
56 13.75    48.2
57 14.00    48.9
58 14.25    49.5
59 14.50    50.2
60 14.75    50.7
61 15.00    51.2
62 15.25    51.6
63 15.50    52.1
64 15.75    52.2
65 16.00    52.4
66 16.25    52.5
67 16.50    52.6
68 16.75    52.7
69 17.00    52.7
70 17.25    52.8
71 17.50    52.8

Answer (score 0):

I think your plot of the derivatives is correct

try this :

```r
df <- structure(list(age = c(0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1, 1.25, 1.5, 1.75, 2, 
                             2.25, 2.5, 2.75, 3, 3.25, 3.5, 3.75, 4, 4.25, 4.5, 4.75, 5, 5.25, 
                             5.5, 5.75, 6, 6.25, 6.5, 6.75, 7, 7.25, 7.5, 7.75, 8, 8.25, 8.5, 
                             8.75, 9, 9.25, 9.5, 9.75, 10, 10.25, 10.5, 10.75, 11, 11.25, 
                             11.5, 11.75, 12, 12.25, 12.5, 12.75, 13, 13.25, 13.5, 13.75, 
                             14, 14.25, 14.5, 14.75, 15, 15.25, 15.5, 15.75, 16, 16.25, 16.5, 
                             16.75, 17, 17.25, 17.5), weight = c(5.9, 7.4, 8.2, 9, 9.5, 10.1, 
                                                                 10.8, 11.2, 11.7, 12.2, 12.6, 13.1, 13.6, 14.3, 14.9, 15.5, 16, 
                                                                 16.5, 17.1, 17.5, 17.9, 18.5, 19.1, 19.7, 20.4, 21.1, 21.7, 22.4, 
                                                                 23, 23.6, 24.4, 25.1, 25.9, 26.6, 27.4, 28.3, 29.1, 29.9, 30.9, 
                                                                 32, 33, 34, 35.2, 36.5, 37.7, 38.9, 40.2, 41.4, 42.7, 43.9, 44.8, 
                                                                 45.7, 46.6, 47.5, 48.2, 48.9, 49.5, 50.2, 50.7, 51.2, 51.6, 52.1, 
                                                                 52.2, 52.4, 52.5, 52.6, 52.7, 52.7, 52.8, 52.8)), row.names = c(NA,-70L), class = "data.frame")
spl <- smooth.spline(df$age , df$weight)
plot(spl)
```

[image]

```r
pr <- predict(spl , deriv = 1)
plot(pr)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-06-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I'm surprised since I would expect that the derivative of a smooth function (weight for age), should also be smooth. I also don't understand the continuous ups and downs of the derivative. I mean, between adjacent points, since there is a constant increase in the original data (weight for age): weight is always increasing through time. So, how is it possible to obtain those ups and downs in the derivative?

Comment: That is where the slope = 0